# how can i make asp.net mvc show a nice 500 error message?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

how can i make asp.net mvc show a nice 500 error message? currently it is tells me that it could not find some view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- An article on the subject by Barry Dahlberg "[ASP.Net MVC Custom Error Pages](http://www.genericerror.com/blog/2009/01/27/ASPNetMVCCustomErrorPages.aspx)".
- Stephen Walther once showed useful technique of handling unknown actions: [ASP.NET MVC Tip #22 -- Return a View without Creating a Controller Action](http://www.superexpert.com/blog/archive/2008/07/21/asp-net-mvc-tip-22-return-a-view-without-creating-a-controller-action.aspx)